# taskdef class org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant, warnings

In Eclipse I am getting 5 warnings for my build.xml:

```
taskdef class.org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask cannot be found
taskdef class.org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTaskcannot be found
taskdef class.org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTaskcannot be found
taskdef class.org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask cannot be found
taskdef class.org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask cannot be found
```

I've set up the following system environment variables (Windows 7)

```
ANT_HOME: C:\apache-ant-1.8.4
CATALINA_HOME: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.29
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34
and have added %ANT_HOME%/bin to PATH
```

edit: I've also added catalina-ant.jar into C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib

More parts of the code:

```
<!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
<!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
<fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
    <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
</fileset>
</path>

<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
<taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you give more information? For example, the taskdef part of your build file.

Comment: Added in the lines of code that causes the warnings

Comment: @Arvin Were you able to get the deploy to work? It seems everyone gets a "insufficient data written" error because setFixedLengthStreamingMode is being set.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think only mentioning the CATALINA_HOME does not work. You need to put the catalina-ant jars to the Ant's class path. In tomcat 7, there 4 jars for this purpose while there was only single jar for this in earlier versions. Please follow this [link](http://paulgrenyer.blogspot.in/2011/11/catalina-ant-for-tomcat-7.html).

As quoted from the link,

> To start with, make sure Tomcat manager is configured for use by
>   Catalina-Ant. Make sure that `manager-script` is included in the roles
>   for one of the users in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml`. For
>   example:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <user name="admin" password="s3cr£t" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

> Catalina-Ant for Tomcat 6 was encapsulated within a single JAR file.
>   Catalina-Ant for Tomcat 7 requires four JAR files. One from
>   `TOMCAT_HOME/bin`:

```
tomcat-juli.jar
```

> and three from `TOMCAT_HOME/lib`:

```
catalina-ant.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-util.jar
```

> There are at least three ways of making the JARs available to Ant:
>
> - Copy the JARs into the `ANT_HOME/lib` folder. Then Ant will just find them.
> - Copy the JARs to a folder within your project that you check into your source control system. Ant then needs a path id to find them:

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
   <fileset dir="${catalina-ant-dir}">
      <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
      <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
      <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
      <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
   </fileset>
</path>
```

> Where `catalina-ant-dir` is the directory with the JARs in. This way you
>   don’t need to modify the Ant installation on every machine you build
>   on. Access the JARs directly from your Tomcat 7 installation. Ant then
>   needs a path id to find them:

```
<path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
           <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
           <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
           <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
               <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

> Where appserver.lib is the path to Tomcat 7’s lib directory and
>   `appserver.home` is the path to Tomcat’s top level installed directory.
>   This way Tomcat 7 is required on every box you build on.
>
> My personal preference is for 2 above.
>
> Now that your Ant script can see the Catalina-Ant JARs you need to
>   tell it what tasks are available. These are most if not all of the
>   tasks that are available to Ant.

```
<taskdef name="catalina-deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-findleaks" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.FindLeaksTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-resources" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ResourcesTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
<taskdef name="catalina-undeploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask" classpathref="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
```

> Finally you need a set of tasks that actually do the work. Although, as you can see above, there are a few tasks I only tend to use the following ones:

```
<target name = "stop-webapp">
       <catalina-stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                         username="${tomcat.username}"
                         password="${tomcat.password}"
                         path="/${webapp.name}"
                         failonerror="false"/>
</target>

<target name = "start-webapp">
    <catalina-start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                       username="${tomcat.username}"
                       password="${tomcat.password}"
                       path="/${webapp.name}"/>
</target>

<target name = "undeploy-webapp">
    <catalina-undeploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                          username="${tomcat.username}"
                          password="${tomcat.password}"
                          path="/${webapp.name}"
                          failonerror="false"/>
</target>

<target name = "deploy-webapp">
    <catalina-deploy url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                        username="${tomcat.username}"
                        password="${tomcat.password}"
                        path="/${webapp.name}"
                        war="file:${war.file}"/>
</target>
```

> `tomcat.manager.url` is the URL where Tomcat manager lives. This is
>   another of the changes from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7. Usually this will
>   be: `http://:8080/manager/text`.
>
> `Tomcat.username` and `Tomcat.password` are the user name and password
>   for Tomcat manager.
>
> `webapp.name` is the name of the Tomcat application that you are
>   deploying.
>
> `war.file` is the path the Tomcat application you are deploying’s WAR
>   file.

Comment: I've already added catalina-ant.jar into C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\lib

Comment: This information was not mentioned in the question and as I said you need to include 4 jars now as mentioned in the link.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the lines of code that causes the warnings. I've also tried adding in the other 3 files in to ANT_HOME/lib but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to follow completely the the link I mentioned?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I didn't realise there were more stuff at the bottom. Will try them now

Answer (score 67):

In tomcat 7 InstallTask is replaced by DeployTask.

change your declaration like

old

```
<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.InstallTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

with

```
 <taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"> 
  <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/> 
 </taskdef>
```

Comment: Thanks I am using Tomcat 7 and changing to DeployTask solved the problem!

Comment: Same problem, same solution!

Comment: Thanks. This is a much better answer than the one above.

Comment: Works for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: Seriously man, that helped a lot. I don't understand why this is not the accepted answer :(

Answer (score 4):

Guess you might have to do this change, since there is no more details in your question

```
<fileset dir="${appserver.home}/common/lib">
<include name="servlet*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

I beleive you might have the above settings in your build.xml Please, change ${appserver.home} to the directory that contains the tomcat installation

```
<fileset dir="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib">
<include name="servlet*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

Comment: Added more details into my post. I've tried what you said but it hasn't removed the warnings unfortunately

Comment: Did you try setting "appserver.home" to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib in the build.properties file ?

Comment: In the build.properties file try to replicate the below, user.home=C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation
appserver.home=${user.home}/Tomcat 5.5
deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

Comment: sorry, where do I set those variables? Java build paths?

Answer (score 4):

In tomcat 7, org.apache.catalina.ant contains a set of Task that can be used to interact with the Manager application to deploy, undeploy, list, reload, start and stop web applications from a running instance of Tomcat.
Replacing InstallTask with DeployTask will solve build problem.

```
<taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>`enter code here`
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipes then you need to change your ant_home location by following below steps,
navigate to window>prefrances>Ant>runtime>classpath>AntHome
click on anthome button and provide your anthome directory path.

and to solv ur problem u need to copy catalina-ant.jar inside anthome/lib folder

Thanks,
Sharad

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following, it will solve your problem:

```
1) Click Eclipse menu Window > Preferences
2) Click Ant > Runtime
3) Under Classpath tab, select Ant Home Entries and click button Add External JARs
4) Browse and open $ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/org.apache.ant_myscrum/lib/catalina-ant.jar
5) Click Apply and OK button
```

[image: Follow the instruction no.3]

[image: Follow the instruction no.4]