# Restart Tomcat from Jenkins or website

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, ant

I have read everywhere how to restart tomcat from Jenkins, but without access.
This: [There is error: C:\Project\Jenkins\${catalina-ant-dir} does not exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122366/taskdef-class-org-apache-catalina-ant-installtask-cannot-be-found)

This: [The plugin is installed, but doesn't show in Jenkins in Build Action](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Capitomcat+Plugin)

Maybe I can use some Shell script - but how? I just want: tomcatstop, tomcatstart

Version: Jenkins - 1.69, Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :)
I just add java class to run startup.bat file to run the tomcat. Then for stop - just kill the tomcat process.

```
    public static void startTomcat(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Start Tomcat...");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\tom6\\bin\\startup.bat");
        System.out.println("Start Completed!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void stopTomcat(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Stop Tomcat...");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start taskkill /F /IM java.exe");
        System.out.println("Stop Completed!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```