# Cause: The name is undefined error from Ant

Tags: ant

Can you someone help me with below error from Ant? I tried adding antlib.xml or antcontrib.properties individually and together but nothing helped.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/apache/antScripts/build-deploy-WAR.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type list
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Here is the build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="WAR Deployment" basedir=".">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="/tmp/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpath="/tmp/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
<target name="deploy" depends="app.status" if="app.notInstalled">
        <deploy url="${name.app.url}" username="${name.app.user}" password="{name.app.password}" path="${name.app.context.path}"/>
</target>

<target name="deploy.war" depends="app.status" if="app.deployable">
        <deploy url="${name.app.url}" username="${name.app.user}" password="{name.app.password}" update="${name.app.update}" path="${name.app.context.path}" war="${name.app.war.path}"/>
</target>

<target name="app.status">
        <property name="running" value="${name.app.context.path}:running"/>
        <property name="stopped" value="${name.app.context.path}:stopped"/>
        <list url="${name.app.url}" outputproperty="ctx.status" username="${name.app.user}" password="{name.app.password}"/>

        <condition property="app.running">
                <contains string="${ctx.status}" substring="${running}"/>
        </condition>

        <condition property="app.stopped">
                <contains string="${ctx.status}" substring="${stopped}"/>
        </condition>

        <condition property="app.notInstalled">
            <and>
                <isfalse value="${app.running}"/>
                <isfalse value="${app.stopped}"/>
            </and>
        </condition>

        <condition property="app.deployable">
            <or>
                <istrue value="${app.notInstalled}"/>
                <and>
                    <istrue value="${app.running}"/>
                    <istrue value="${name.app.update}"/>
                </and>
                <and>
                    <istrue value="${app.stopped}"/>
                    <istrue value="${name.app.update}"/>
                </and>
            </or>
        </condition>
        <condition property="app.undeployable">
            <or>
                <istrue value="${app.running}"/>
                <istrue value="${app.stopped}"/>
            </or>
        </condition>
</target>
</project>
```

I have all the tomcat 4 required jar files.

```
catalina-ant
tomcat-coyote
tomcat-util
tomcat-juli
```

Tomcat Version: 9.0.22.

Comment: Although you've added taskdefs for antcontrib the "list" task is part of the catalina-ant package, so you need the right taskdef for that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122366/taskdef-class-org-apache-catalina-ant-installtask-cannot-be-found

Comment: Thanks that helps! Have a another question, am getting below error if the war file is big.  I tried to increase the maxPostsize and below on web.xml but no luck       <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
"" java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
  Suppressed: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3609)